# Convert csv to db in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a csv file with `;` separator. I would like to convert it into `.db`. I follow advice here: https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#section_8

In my Ubuntu terminal I use:

1. `sqlite3 ex1`

Then I try:

`.mode list`

`.separator ";"`

`.import odberatel.csv odberatel`

`.save odberatel.db`

But When I look on the odberatel.db in Db Browser for SQLite it seems that is not separated correctly:

[image]

What do I do wrong, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the same [sqlite doc](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#importing_csv_files):

> Note that it is important to set the "mode" to "csv" before running the ".import" command.